# Default browser in Google maps on iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, google-maps

iPhone recently allowed me to set *Chrome* as the default browser, but this has not affected browsing from **google maps**. When clicking on a business location in google maps, then clicking on the website, it still always opens in safari. Any way for me to change this?

Answer (score 1):

If I go to a *business location* and on their website via the *google maps*-app, the website is opened in the internal browser of google maps (and not in a external browser like *safari* or *chrome*.

When I click the icon on the right bottom, it's open the recent website in safari, but this icon refer to the safari browser.

[image]

Comment: If I copy the URL from the Google maps internal browser, and paste it somewhere else, it says "pasted from safari". HOWEVER, if I click the icon in the lower right it opens in Chrome, so that's a solution albeit with an extra step.

Comment: When I copy a link from any website in *google maps* and paste it anywhere, it pops up "**...pasted from google maps**". So I don't know what's going wrong by you... Go through the official *apple* documentation about [Change the default web browser or email app on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211336). Maybe it will help to go through the settings again

Comment: Click on the link in Google maps, THEN copy the URL from the address bar, then paste. See what happens.